# When and How we should specify "clusterIP" inside the "service.yaml" file?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, deployment, service, cassandra

I tried to deploy `mysql` and `cassandra` databases using [kubernetes.io/docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/) instructions. In both of them, within the `service.yaml` files, they use   `clusterIP: None` like following:

For `cassandra`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
  clusterIP: None
```

For `mysql`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
```

I would like to know, why they don't specify `clusterIP` in the `service.yaml` file? How should we specify it and what would be the use cases?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using **headless service**. Whenever the `clusterIP` is set to none that means that it is a **headless service**. **StatefulSets** currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. Because unlike the **stateless** deployments the statefulset pods will have Stable, unique network identifiers(pod names).

To answer your question we don't set `clusterIP` in the case of **headless** service. We need to set it as `none`. So the service will use the unique identifier(DNS lookups) of a **statefulset** pods and assign IP on its own at the time of communication.

To know more in detail with example you can refer to this [offical k8 document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#using-statefulsets)